# Triangle using CSS

Tags: html, css

```css
.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 100vh solid yellow;
  border-right: 100vw solid rgb(13, 13, 54);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Can anyone explain this code to me that how does it is going to print triangle.

In my point of view it should to give the the a border at top of the web page of yellow and a blue border on the right of the web pages.

Answer (score 0):

> In my point of view it should to give the the a border at top of the web page of yellow and a blue border on the right

That's exactly what it does.  Though note the *sizes* of the top and left borders.  They are intended to take up *the entire viewport*.  Open your browser's development tools and inspect the styling on that element.  Note the *thickness* of the borders in the resulting "box" display:

[image]

So what you're essentially seeing rendered on the page is the border of an element.  Specifically only the top and right border.  The two of which are different colors and take up the entire page.

The "triangle" effect is simply relying on the fact that the rendered boundary *between* any two borders is a slanted line.  You can see that line more effectively if you reduce the sizes of your borders (and give the element itself a height and width) to see them as "borders":

```css
.triangle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-top: 20px solid yellow;
  border-right: 20px solid rgb(13, 13, 54);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: I wonder how the slanting separation has been created, that's where I'm stuck!

Comment: @aks: Because the boundary between two multi-pixel borders is a slant from the outer corner to the inner corner.  Think of it like the pieces of a picture frame.  This code isn't "creating" the slanted line, it's simply using the existence of a perceived slanted line to create the illusion of one.